# Azure ACS session lifetime

Tags: azure, wif, acs

Say I sign into my site with ACS. Then close the browser, then reopen the site... it asks me to sign-in again. I would like it so it doesn't ask me to signin for a week or so after I authenticate with ACS the first time. How does one go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following attributes, this will persist the cookie with an extended lifetime.

```
<wsFederation ... persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true">
    <CookieHandler ... persistentSessionLifetime="60"/>
    ...
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't authenticate against ACS. ACS is an intermediary between your app and an identity provider (e.g. LiveID, Google, Facebook, etc).

If you set "remember me" with any of these sites (and if they support it), then you will not be asked for username/password the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, that the description about persistentSessionLifetime in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568663.aspx) is not true. For example, if you set it to 1.6:13:45.0, the cookie will expire after 30 hours (1 day + 6 hours) 13 minutes and 45 seconds +/- the maximumClockSkew from <identityConfiguration>. So the description from MSDN should be like the one from TimeSpan: [-]d.hh:mm:ss.ff. I hope Microsoft changes the wrong description.